# Strings assignment in C language

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *c;
c = "hello";
c = "name";
return 0;
}
```

The above code compiles fine but below gives seg fualt at run time

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
char *c;
c = "hello";
*c = 'A';
return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can't modify string literals, which is what `c` points to.  Try using the string literal to initialize an *array*, instead of a pointer: `char c[] = "hello";`'

Comment: ok but why the above code works. There we are modifying it other name...?

Comment: Many answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194), including a link to the [old C FAQ list answer](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html).

Comment: @MustansirD because the first example is pointing `c` to somewhere else, it's not modifying the existing string.

Comment: Understood Thanks everyone.
Can anyone help with a program and a tool like nm in linux to check in which memory the variables occupy the space like stack heap data seg and code seg...?